# A function $f$ that is not in any $L^p$ but the measure of $\{|f|>t\}$ is bounded by $C/t$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

How can I find a function $f$ such that $f \notin L^{p} (\mathbb{R})$ for all $p$ but you can find a constant $c>0$ for it with

$m(x \in \mathbb{R} \,  s.t.  |f(x)|>t) \leq \frac{c}{t}$  for $\forall t$

I tried $f(x)={1 \over x^2}$ since $f \notin L^{p} (\mathbb{R})$ for all $p$, but it looks like this is not the right answer. I guess we could use the Chevyshev's inequality on $f(x)$ , the measure theoretic one (see Section Measure-theoretic statement in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)

Comment: What is $p$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Do you mean $| f(x) | > t$ instead of $|f (x) > t|$?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what  you tried for $f.$

Comment: @copper.hat for all $p$

Comment: @ Heterbrij @zhw   I added more details. Thanks,.

Comment: You didn't try $f(x) = 1/x$?

Comment: @ zhw it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 1/x, x \ne 0.$ Then $f\not \in L^p(\mathbb {R}), 0 < p \le \infty,$ but $m(\{x: |f(x)| > t\}) = 2/t$ for all $t>0.$